# Why does the Google search result of an AMP page have "IIS Windows Server"?

Tags: amp-html

The Google search result of an AMP page shows the following:
[image]

The source page shows the following:

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Article",
        "headline": "Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)",
        "description": "Frequently asked questions.",
        "datePublished": "2013-11-13T12:02:41Z",
        "dateModified": "2019-04-22T12:02:41Z",

        "author": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "url": "www.ipcent.com"
        },

...

        }
    </script>
```

Could anyone offer a tip on how to remove IIS Windows Server from the search result?

**Edit[2021-03-13]**

The response header:

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/home/faq
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: x.x.x.x:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: private
content-length: 124604
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Sat, 13 Mar 2021 17:10:54 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
:authority: www.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /home/faq
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.amp-HDkFcm02h0bjU1WTePTM5w; _gid=GA1.2.335544267.1615637648; paddlejs_checkout_variant={"inTest":true,"controlGroup":false,"isForced":false,"variant":"multipage-radio-payment"}; paddlejs_campaign_referrer=www.google.com; __atuvc=3%7C10; __atssc=google%3B2
pragma: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: check your response header; may be coming from server name

Comment: Per your suggestion, I edited the question by adding the response header.